# Split() at a meta character * with pyspark and Java

Tags: java, dataframe, pyspark, hive, string-formatting

I've fighting with this code to split the column name_surname in 2 differents columns. The content of the column name_surname is stored like i.e.: `David*Green` so the purpose of these query is to separate the content in 2 columns name and surname where '*' is found.

The query in java is as follows:

```
final String addressQuery = String.format(
                "select '104' as id, " +
                        "trim(split(name_surname,'\\*')[1]) as name, " +
                        "trim(split(name_surname,'\\*')[0]) as surname, " +
                        "address, " +
                        "zip , " +
                        "from address_info ");
```

Then this is saved as a dataframe:

```
DataFrame addressInt = sqlContext.sql(addressQuery);
```

When running this String like this, I've the following exception:
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0

After reading another stackoverflow post, I found that for pyspark this same query should be modified as follows in the split lines:

```
"trim(split(name_surname,'\\\\*')[1]) as name, " +
"trim(split(name_surname,'\\\\*')[0]) as surname, "
```

But then when executing I got a NullPointerException error.

Do you guys know how can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code lines that give ´NullPointerException`.

Comment: I can write it here but I think it's not relevant: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.address.utils.ProcessDataframes$1.call(ProcessDataframes.java:63)

Comment: The method I mean

Comment: 1.  There is no reason to use String.format when you’re only passing one argument.  2.  Edit your question show the full stack trace for each exception you’re getting.  Currently, we have no idea what you did to cause those exceptions, so we can’t suggest a remedy.  3.  The stack traces will show which lines of your code generated the exceptions.  Include those exact lines of code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you split your task into 2 subtasks. do the split first and than use the split result in the query. Your split than becomes very simple:

```
String[] names= name_surname.split("\\*");
```

Also your query will look simpler and you will only need to invoke `split()` method once instead of twice, as in your code, plus you can validate that both name and surname are not blanks before running your query.

Comment: He's not passing name and surname into the query, he's retrieving them _from_ the query. But your suggestion could also work well in reverse: get name_surname from the query and then do the split in Java instead of doing it in SQL.

Comment: @k314159 thanks for correction, and yes my idea stands. In this case I'd say splitting this operation in 2 makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... After reading another stackoverflow post, I found that for pyspark this same query should be modified as follows in the split lines ..."*

Correct, you'll need 4 slashes there.

> *"... then when executing I got a NullPointerException error ..."*

And, in your comments you said,

> *"... Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.address.utils.ProcessDataframes$1.call(ProcessDataframes.java:63) ..."*

So, the error is on line 63 of the *ProcessDataframes* class.
Possibly you're providing a *null* object somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue was solved by 1) adding 2 more backslashes for scaping when running pyspark and 2) adding a where clause like this:

```
final String addressQuery = String.format(
                "select '104' as id, " +
                        "trim(split(name_surname,'\\\\*')[1]) as name, " +
                        "trim(split(name_surname,'\\\\*')[0]) as surname, " +
                        "address, " +
                        "zip , " +
                        "from address_info " +
                        "where name_surname like '%s'", "%*%");
```

Comment: There's no need to use String.format, you can just simply do `final String addressQuery = "select... where name_surname like '%*%'";`